# Methods references

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a task to implement simple java code with two Methods and two dimensional array.
But there is some simple mistake I cannot find.
It's line

> getArray(nc);

"nc" underlined as "might not have been initialized"

```
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       int nc[][];
       getArray(nc);
       for (int i=0;i<nc.length;i++)
       {
           System.out.println();
           for(int k=0;k<nc.length;k++)
           {
               System.out.print(nc[k]+", ");
           }
       }
   }

   static void getArray(int[][]nc){
       for (int i=0;i<nc[0].length;i++)
       {
           for(int k=0;k<nc.length;k++)
           {
               nc[k][i]=1+(int)(Math.random()*100);
           }
       }    
   }
}
```

If I do like this

> public static void main (int nc[][]) {

it tells that there is no main method. Thanks.

Comment: _"nc" underlined as "might not have been initialized"_ Isn't that error clear? `int nc[][];` This is just a declaration, not an assignment.

Comment: You use obfuscator? Your code not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int nc[][];
```

The above line only *declares* a variable `nc`, which is of type array of arrays of ints. But it doesn't initialize any array. The variable's value is `null`.

So you need to create an array:

```
int[][] nc = new int[10][10];
```

for example, which declares the nc variable, and assigns a 10x10 two-dimensional array (filled with 0) to the variable.

```
public static void main (int nc[][])
```

This would not declare a main method, because a main method MUST take an array of Strings as unique parameter. And this array of Strings contains all the arguments passed to your program when executing it. For example:

```
java com.foo.bar.MyApp hello world
```

would call the main method of the class `com.foo.bar.MyApp` with an array containing `"hello"` and `"world"`.

Answer (score 1):

As your method is written, `getArray(int[][])` receives an array and fills it up. However, if you look at the beginning of your `main` method, you never initialize it.

You could just do it in the `main` method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int nc[][] = new int [10][10]; // Or any other size
    getArray(nc);
...
```

However, this doesn't "feel" like Java code - it feels like C. In Java, since we have garbage collection, and don't need to worry about returning objects allocated inside methods, you could just rewrite `getArray` to handle (and return) the allocation:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int nc[][] = getArray();
    /* The rest of your main method */
}

private static int[][] getArray() {
    int nc[][] = new int[10][10]; // Or any other size
    for (int i=0;i<nc[0].length;i++)
       {for(int k=0;k<nc.length;k++)
       {nc[k][i]=1+(int)(Math.random()*100);}}    }}
```

Comment: +1 for the better design suggestion